# Call functions in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

The user has to choose between the regular menu and the veggie menu.

However, I have difficulties calling them in the main() function. Here is what I already have:

```
def displayMenu():
   print ("1. regular menu\n 2. veggie menu")
   user_choice = input("Which one do you want to choose? (1 or 2)")
   return user_choice

def regularMenu(rmenu):
   rmenu =  open("regularmenu.txt","r")
   for line in rmenu:
       line.strip ()
       print(line)

def veggieMenu(vmenu):
   vmenu =  open("veggiemenu.txt","r")
   for line in vmenu:
       line.strip ()
       print(line)

def main(): # Here is where I have difficulty
   # If the user chooses 1, print regular menu
   # If the user chooses 2, print veggie menu
   # I don't know how to make the if statement here
```

Comment: As in the answer of the duplicate but change `'move'` and `'jump'` with `'1'` and `'2'`.

Comment: Your `displayMenu()` function returns the user choice, so why can you not operate on the return value in your `main()`?

Comment: @JAB Thanks. I just started learning functions. I'm not sure how to call it in main ().

Comment: @pythh The same way you called the other functions you've used in your program so far. Note that your `main()` will itself need to be called at some point as Python does not follow the same behavior as C/C++/Java in having a function that's called automatically at program start.